# Jenkins plugin to run validation checks against the build

Tags: java, jenkins

I would like to run some validation checks against projects that jenkins builds. The validation checks would run against files from the project being built and report violations. I already have a core java application which can test the file types I require but, being a complete beginner with jenkins I'm unsure where to start with the jenkins integration! Any help is welcome!

Comment: Have you looked at the LARGE list of plugins Jenkins provides to do code validation? Have you tried any yet?

Comment: Its not code validation that I want to do, its more xml xsl etc...basically the non java bits which sonar can deal with

Comment: There is a sonar plugin: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Hudson+and+Jenkins+Plugin

Comment: Yes but its not the low level java code validation that I want to do....its more that I wish to validate that the correct high level business processes are being followed.

Comment: I'm confused. First you say you want "the non java bits which sonar can deal with" and then you reject sonar... I suppose if nothing else, you can use ant to call your validation code and fail the build if your validation checks fail. Otherwise you are writing your own Jenkins plugin for this tool you have to run your validation. What tool are you using? Custom home-brewed validation?

Comment: Apologies, what I meant was that sonar can deal with the java bits and my application will deal with the higher level stuff.

Comment: @Kane I think for what I want an ant script is the best way. I'll accept it if you post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ant to call your validation code and fail the build if your validation checks fail. Otherwise you are writing your own Jenkins plugin for this tool you have to run your validation. Anything that fails the ant build also fails the Jenkins build.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to modify your existing validation application, or make a transformation step that makes it produce files that Jenkins Violations Plugin can scan

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Violations

Hopefully you can pretend that your application is e.g. findbugs or one of the already supported checkers by just producing output in the same format.

Answer (score -1):

[Violations](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Violations) is frecuently used, as mentioned previously, to collect and present the findings of many other tools: checkstyle, pmd, cpd, findbugs and many others, most of which allow to create custom rules, although not always easily.

Maven plugins Jenkins can launch for specific verifications the output of which you can, of course, grep:

- [maven dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/).  The goals *analyze*, *analyze-dep-mgt*, *analyze-duplicate* are useful to check multiple situations with the project dependencies
- [maven verifier plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-verifier-plugin/). Verifies the existence or non-existence of files/directories and optionally checks file content against a regular expression
- [maven enforcer plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/). To check whether the pom.xml elements satisfy certain rules. How to create your own rules is [well documented](http://ttp://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-api/writing-a-custom-rule.html). And repositories of existing rules exist out there such as: [enforcer rules](https://github.com/ceilfors/enforcer-rules), [extra-enforcer rules](http://www.mojohaus.org/extra-enforcer-rules/)...